# How do I make a form in the list view in django admin?

Tags: django, forms, django-admin

I want to add a few drop down boxes for properties of related objects to the list view (or whatever `localhost:8000/admin/my_site/my_item` is called) but I can't find any way to inline a custom form there.

The best I can do so far is set choices for a field on this object and then percolate them to the sub-objects, but I think there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Mixin overriding get_context_data, in it load the form and inject it to the context, then override your get method in your view and manipulated the data provided.
I can't provide more since I don't know what exactly is your example.